# Add/delete list item using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, list-item

I need knockout js code to add/delete a list item. Any ideas?

Comment: you should try it yourself and then ask if something doesn't work. What did you write so far?

Answer (score 3):

Did you even try to google? 
http://mysharepointlearnings.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/knockout-js-with-sharepoint-2013-app-ii/

There are plenty of results regarding your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response..I am basic learner of knockoutjs, so would be helpful if i can get some code reg this. The above mentioned link is blocked for me here..any other alternate references plz...